# An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. Primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have trouble with saving data to table.

When I try to insert data I have this error:

[image: Screen]

Here is Inner Exception:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'aspnet-SmartSolutions-20170124034333.dbo.Clients'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

But Id is auto increment:

[image]

Where is my trouble?

Comment: You only show a piece of your code in a screenshot. It would be more useful if you posted the code. Are you setting the ID to null from your code anywhere?

Comment: The `Id` field seems OK, although you may have to designate it as Primary Key, but I'm not sure if having no PK would cause this. Other than that a PK is always recommended. Also check that the actual table in your DB matches with what you would expect / what you see here.

Comment: what does your entity look like? post some code

Comment: which entity framework approach you have used i.e Code First or Database First approach?

Comment: Sorry dudes. It was end of working day and I was to tired. I want to write to Clients table and watching in Client table. Sorry.